# Gecoder Add seperate values to Database for City State

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, location, geocode

**using the geocoder gem**

Can someone tell me can i get the City and State to automatically be entered into the database if i add those columns.

in the example below i am passing in `:cs` witch is an `address`

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cs, :latitude, :longitude
  geocoded_by :cs
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :cs_changed?
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :origin_id
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :dest_id
end
```

I need to save the geocoded city and state that was parsed.

either that or figure out how to get the gecoder to give me a list of locations in a particular group of states from the database

I would be passing in array `[mo,il,ks,ar]` or string `"mo,il,ks,ar"`

i have tried:

```
Location.near([mo,il,ks,ar])
```

I can however do:

```
Location.near("springfield, mo", 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after alot of research i added the columns City and State and did this:

Actual Working Code: this will add the City and State from the Results...

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cs, :latitude, :longitude, :city, :state

  after_validation :geocode, :if => :cs_changed?
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :origin_id
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :dest_id

  geocoded_by :cs do |obj, results|
    geo = results.first
    if geo
      obj.latitude = geo.latitude
      obj.longitude = geo.longitude
      obj.city  = geo.city
      obj.state = geo.state_code
    end
  end
end
```

Would also like to say that my input field is utilizing the GeoComplete Gem that gives valid `City, St, Country` combinations before it gets here so should be able to find the right location